Measuring departure between the posterior predictive distribution and the true data generating distribution
Suppose, I am trying to measure the departure between the posterior predictive distribution and the data generating distribution.
So, in this case, assume that there is a single observation $$X \sim N\left( \frac{1}{\theta},1 \right)$$ where $\theta > 0$.
Now, we employ two priors on $\theta$, say $\pi_1(\theta) \equiv C^{+}(0,1)$ (Half-Cauchy), supported over $(0,\infty)$ and $\pi_2(\theta) \equiv \text{Gamma}(3,10)$.
Empirically, it can be seen that for large values of $\theta$, the Cauchy posterior estimates (median of the MCMC samples drawn from the posterior) are more closely aligned to the true values than the Gamma posterior estimates. But is there a way to see that theoretically? I mean is there a way to say that the KL divergence (or any suitable divergence metric) between the Cauchy posterior predictive distribution and the true data generating distribution $N \left(\frac{1}{\theta},1\right)$ is larger than the Gamma posterior predictive distribution and the true data generating distribution? Since this is a probabilistic statement, makes sense to state that with high probability.
If someone knows references regarding similar approaches in the Bayesian literature, feel free to drop in a few names.
Thanks!

Your stipulation that $\theta > 0$ is in contradiction to a Cauchy prior, so it is unclear exactly what you are proposing in this case.  With a gamma prior, this is not an issue.

My bad, it should be a half-Cauchy prior which means that you are truncating the negative part of Cauchy and its supported over $(0,\infty)$.

"Empirically,  it can be seen that for large values of $θ$ ...".  That should be no surprise.  For $\theta> 0.59168$ the density of the half-Cauchy is higher than the density of your Gamma distribution and for large $\theta$ it is much higher.   If you think $\theta$ may be quite likely to be large then your particular Gamma distribution is not the appropriate prior.

Some random remarks:

Statistics questions, unless dealing with heavy probability theory, are probably much better directed at stats.stackexchange.com.

Your question

Suppose, I am trying to measure the departure between the posterior predictive distribution and the data generating distribution.

already puts you in the very complex situation of performing a frequentist analysis of Bayesian methods, I guess? You would probably need to define this much more precisely in order for this concept to be interesting to study.

I really don't understand what your model is supposed to represent. I understand the probability model, but I really don't know what situation it is supposed to capture. Is this something that comes up in practice?

Such analyses are typically done in the large data limit. This ensures some amount of regularity. The details would vary depending on exactly the model we choose to study. In your example, you have a single datapoint instead, which is going to be problematic.

I don't have a great reference to share on this topic further. The van de vaart asymptotics book has some elements, but it is a very rough introduction to the field. There are some great result in there, but it fails to give a clear overall picture. I don't know of any great reviews of the topic.

The general problem of choosing a prior is a very thorny one. The best perspective on this is Gelman and his students. He has a new book coming out on this topic which might offer more clarity. This book has some interesting points. (NB: each chapter has different authors; it reads like a compilation of articles). Overall, I think many expert statisticians know how to recognize a good prior from a bad one, but I don't think there currently is an all-encompassing framework to make this perfectly rigorous.


Let me know if you want additional information.
